# Jquery FADE in/out CONTENT

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, events

I needed a bit of help

My problem is I need a Fade in Fade out function that keeps repeating my Div Content about every 7 seconds. Content 1 will appear, then Content 2 will fade in, then Content 3 fade in after content 2 fades out, and it keeps repeating.

I wrote a script but it seems to not working properly. What am I doing wrong? How can I make this more efficient? Any guide will be helpful.

THE HTML inside of a UL wrapped in LIs

```
<ul>
     <li class=”thecontent”> CONTENT 1</li>
     <li class=”thecontent”> CONTENT 2</li>
     <li class=”thecontent” > CONTENT 3</li>
     <li class=”thecontent” > CONTENT 4</li>
  <ul>
```

THE CSS

```
ul li.thecontent{ display:none;}
```

THE JQUERY

```
  $(document).load(function(){
     function fadeMyContent() {
     $(".content:hidden:first").fadeIn(700).delay(1000).fadeOut(700,
 function() {    $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());   
 fadeMyContent();    });
       }
     fadeMyContent();
```

Comment: I could be wrong but this behaviour will just fade between Content 1 and 2, because after Content 1 gets hidden, :hidden:first will return content1 again. Try something like $('.content:visible').next() and check if .next().length === 0. If this is the case, fade back to content 1 and it should repeat properly

Comment: @GNi33 I believe the `$(this).appendTo($(this).parent())` statement moves the first `li` to the end of the list hence avoiding the problem you mentioned.

Comment: @Ali Just realised this behaviour. That actually is a good way to do this, to be honest, because the element does not get cloned either. Still I prefer to keep the DOM as it is and just move between items. I'm not sure how this affects performance, when you are permanently moving elements in the DOM.

Comment: @GNi33 I would not change the DOM either, I had created an answer that did this without modifying the DOM however considering that others got this code working I figured there was no point. Personally he should use `setInterval` and maintain an array of the elements and hide / show them in order.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go. In your code the class name in the selector is wrong and also the double quotes enclosing the class names in the markup is not correct.

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wV6Tk/)**

```
$(function(){
     function fadeMyContent() {

         $(".thecontent:first").fadeIn(700).delay(1000).fadeOut(700,
             function() {    
                     $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());   
                     fadeMyContent();    
             });
      }
     fadeMyContent();
});
```

**Mark up**

```
<ul>
     <li class='thecontent'> CONTENT 1</li>
     <li class='thecontent'> CONTENT 2</li>
     <li class='thecontent'> CONTENT 3</li>
     <li class='thecontent'> CONTENT 4</li>
<ul
```

Comment: This is perfect, the only thing is that I'm working on now its to make it fade in and fafe out more softer. basically my content is images, so as 1 images is fading out, i must see the next image coming in...that's the only thing i'm playing with now. Thanks.

Comment: YYes i will. hey ShankarSangol i was trying to get it to smooth out better so as 1 images is fading out, i must see the next image coming in...that's the only thing i'm . I tried by making the fade in seconds and fade out seconds higher and lower respectively but no luck. 

Any suggestion to accomplish this

Comment: I just increased the duration of fadeIn/Out, it works as expected take a look http://jsfiddle.net/wV6Tk/1/

Comment: Yes i did tried that already..but  I'm talking about the white area that shows before the content comes in. As Content one fades out, i wanted Content two to be coming in at the same time...with no White area to show

Comment: That is simply not possible with this logic. You have to layout the elements absolutely positioned and then animate them in parallel.

Comment: Hey  ShankarSangoli I was still getting stock on this a bit. Needed some help on a different layout possible? You suggested i will need to lay it out different and animaite them parallel?
You guide will be appreciated.

Comment: Hey ShankarSangoli i still was not able to figure this out, any luck here?

Comment: Thanks! I was also looking for this and you've done it so simply

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the correct class?

.content in the jQuery code and "thecontent" in the markup. How exactly is it not working properly? Is the timer not working is it fading too fast, not showing anything at all?

Comment: sorry suppose to be thecontent

Answer (score 0):

luckily this is what i am working on right now lol

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.clicked').click(function(){
        $(this).next('.nextSibling').toggle('slow');
    }); 
});
```